# COM Port access denied

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

Even though I could see many solutions for my question title, my scenario seems different.
I just connect my Telemetry Radio via USB and it gets assigned with COM4 Port access. (which we can change later for any other port from System Management)
I created an application to connect to the radio with the serial port under the com port access given. 
When I executed the application, I could see the com port to access. When I connect, It gives me the exception of "COM Port access denied". I was checking whether any other application or process uses the com port or the device, It seems clear NO.
But at sometimes, like 25-30 times once, I could connect to the device. This seems quite unique for me. 
It gives me exception many times. But gets connected once in a while.

Any possible reasons or any ways to find out how to see which process/application uses the device/com port so that, we can stop that application and let this application make use of the port.

Comment: can you connect to it with another program?  this is not really a programming question

Comment: I tried with another application to access the device with the same COM port. Even there I get the same error. At the same time, I tried restarting my system. my bad, Still no use.

Comment: then you've got a non programming problem to do with your hardware

Comment: the same reader works fine if I try to access from ubuntu terminal using ros. But couldn't access from c#